# How to import multiple version of opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

The program uses 2 version of opencv  i.e **opencv 2.4 and opencv 3.0 .**.By default the program uses opencv 2.4 but i have to use k-means algorithm from opencv 3.0 .

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__

output: 2.4.11
```

how to use the other version of opencv as well in a single program.
language in which i am trying to import opencv is python 2.7

Comment: Does v3.0 lack any features of v2.4? If not, why not exclusively use 3.0?

Comment: @ian_itor The project is completely developed using opencv2.4 and I need to just add a feature that uses opencv3.0. Migrating the complete code now to opencv3 will take a lot of time for us.

Comment: No it won't take a lot of time @kkk, The API is largely similar for Opencv2 and Opencv3.

Comment: possibly you can change the name of cv2.so as cv_two.so & import cv2 as cv_two